# Mobile UX: Open full page overlay by clicking on a tab

Tags: mobile, ios, tabs, modal-windows, overlay

I am creating a mobile UX in which the user presses on a tab in order to capture a 3D view of an object. Clicking on the tab opens an image capture overlay straightaway. The other 2 tabs as shown in the picture below render lists on being clicked.

Looking forward to your thoughts on whether this is an acceptable UX pattern/ practice.

[image: Tab to open a modal]

Answer (score 1):

The tabs on the top will only work when the tab selector is retained in all three tabs. One should be able to toggle between 'List view, 3d view, Summary' without having to stop and understand how to go back in to the previous tab selection. In your screenshots, the controls are clearly not being retained in the 3D view and the user has to cancel out the view to get back to the tabs. This interaction can be confusing, please do not proceed.

For a correct implementation, You can check by choosing any of the 3d models from the [AR quick Look examples on iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/) for how Apple iOS 14 handles a similar toggle between looking at an object in 3D view or AR view. The idea is to be able to maintain the tabs(segmented control) on the top so as to let the user go back the same way they are used to navigating between the segments.

It also seems like the original choice for having the tabs is not the best in this case. I notice these 3 tabs seem more like sequences or progressions. By which I mean, they are ordered steps. If that is the case, it's much better to not have the tabs on top and rather only have a summary list view screen that can be filled up with user entered dat and filling the 3d data is just a section among the many fields in this List view. Tapping on the input area for 3d should trigger a a modal sheet flying in from the bottom to help with the 3d view. Thus summary screen is basically the list view and the 3d data together from where the user can submit the form finally. For such an example, look into adding a photo for a new contact that you are creating on iOS 14.